# Skewed background div positioned to the content block's right hand bottom corner

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, skew

See the following example

```css
.nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
.nav-bar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10.938rem;
  background: #1a5733;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: initial;
  display: block;
}
.nav-menu {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="nav-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sobre</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Destaques</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contactos</a>
    <br>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the green skewed *nav-bar:before* to position bottom at right hand side of the *nav-container* so it's overflow matches the content in the container:
[image: please note that for the purpose of the screenshot, I modified bottom to -25px]
(please note that for the purpose of the screenshot, I modified bottom to -25px the original value 0 produces random results on screen resize)

Is it possible to calculate the bottom difference based on the 1.6deg skew applied to the `nav-bar:before` element? Please consider responsiveness.

Or is it just a case of adjusting manually with media query breakpoints?

Comment: If anyone is interested, this was applied here http://covema.pt/pt/inicio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `transform-origin: right bottom` to the element to get this done. Setting the transform origin as `right bottom` means that the transform is applied by keeping that point as fixed.

```css
.nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
.nav-bar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10.938rem;
  background: #1a5733;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  transform: skewY(-1.6deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  display: block;
}
.nav-menu {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="nav-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sobre</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Destaques</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contactos</a>
    <br>
  </nav>
</div>
```